# inline javascript not being executed in angular routing template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem :
I am using angular.js and have implemented routing. This worked also well for me and displayed the html code in the templates. But I have the following problem: 
My template looks something like this:

```
<div id="map_canvas"  style="width:95%; height:800px; margin-top:5%; "></div>
        <div id="legend"><h3>Legend</h3></div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('Hi');
            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.209500, 16.370691),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);



                //Markers


                var lat_cat0;
                var long_cat0;
                var markerContent ="";
                var iconNames = ["NotAvailable", "VeryBad", "Bad", "Medium", "Good", "VeryGood"];
                for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $.getJSON("../../../Data/JSONs/randomdata_cat"+i+".json", function (result) {
                            $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                                markerContent = "Date: " + field.Timestamp + " - Downstream: " + field.Upstream.toFixed(2) + " Mbit/s - Upstream: " + field.Downstream.toFixed(2) + " Mbit/s";
                                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    content: markerContent
                                });

                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(field.Long, field.Lat),
                                    animation: google.maps.Animation.Bounce,
                                    map: map,
                                    icon: 'images/Speed_'+iconNames[i]+'.png'
                                });
                                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                });


                            });
                        });

                    });
                }


                //Legend

                var icons = {
                    notAvailable: {
                        name: 'notAvailable',
                        icon: 'images/Speed_NotAvailable.png'
                    },
                    verybad: {
                        name: 'verybad',
                        icon: 'images/Speed_VeryBad.png'
                    },
                    bad: {
                        name: 'bad',
                        icon: 'images/Speed_Bad.png'
                    },
                    medium: {
                        name: 'medium',
                        icon: 'images/Speed_Medium.png'
                    },
                    good: {
                        name: 'good',
                        icon: 'images/Speed_Good.png'
                    },
                    verygood: {
                        name: 'verygood',
                        icon: 'images/Speed_VeryGood.png'
                    }
                };


                var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
                for (var key in icons) {
                    var type = icons[key];
                    var name = type.name;
                    var icon = type.icon;
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
                    legend.appendChild(div);
                }



                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);


            }

            function loadScript() {
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=fds&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
                document.body.appendChild(script);

            }



            window.onload = loadScript;

        </script>
```

So i can only see the two divs but not the map that should be created as well as the console output. 
And yes it works if I implement it in a "static" html page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you using jquery, check jquery is loaded, before doing anything

Comment: I have loaded jquery that lets the console output execute but not the google maps api...

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {} is inside forloop ????????? why it should above console.log("Hi");

Comment: Don't think about the logic behind the code. Exactly the same code works on static html pages. So the only thing that changed is the fact that it is now used in a angualr routing template..

Comment: change this line window.onload = loadScript; to this window.onload = loadScript(); you will be got go what you have got above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

Just implemented jquery and the Gmaps api itself into the main page. 
I thought it is enough to link the google maps source in the javascript part on the template page